# No permitir seleccionar en Datepicker de materialize los días pasados

Tags: jquery, materialize, jquery-datepicker

¿Cómo no permitir seleccionar en Datepicker de materialize los días pasados?

Actualmente tengo esto pero no me funciona

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function(){
   $('select').material_select();
         $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
         $(".slider").slider({interval: 5000});
         $('.parallax').parallax();
   $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
  dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
  opacity: .8, // Opacity of modal background
  in_duration: 300, // Transition in duration
  out_duration: 200, // Transition out duration
  ready: function() {  }, // Callback for Modal open
  complete: function() {  } // Callback for Modal close
});


 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
     minDate: 0,  //no permite seleccionar los días pasados
     selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
     selectYears: 5, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
     format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' // formato de fecha
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La opción es `min` y en lugar de 0 deberías darle la fecha actual, así:

```js
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  min: new Date(),
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <input type="date" class="datepicker">
```

Comment: Equiso gracias me sirvió